# Emotional home?

Tags: demande-de-mot

How do you express, in French, that a person feels like an emotional home to you? Something like:

> She is my home.

I am specifically looking for a noun to fit a phrase such as "Elle est ma vie", not a paraphrase such as "With her, I feel as if I was at home".

Comment: Can't think about anything else but be someone else "[essentiel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKGA7nw3DrQ)" or maybe "[âme sœur](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%82me_s%C5%93ur)" because `Selon Ramban, chacun des partenaires séparés aspire à retrouver la présence de l'autre, dont il a gardé la marque, dans sa chair comme dans son âme` as a life quest and life only goal (if you reach it, you are ok whatever the place).

Comment: Also, ***foyer*** is close to *refuge*. I feel like there must be other options drawing from the religious lexicon (lieu saint / de recueillement / alcove / chapelle), but I can't find a suitable one. *Sanctuaire* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest:

> C'est mon refuge.

thus you can stick to one word while still keeping the idea of both feeling at home and wanting to be there.

Obviously, using *c'* implies you've mentioned "her" before so that it is clear *c'* refers to "her". Can be adapted to whatever context you have.

> Elle est mon refuge.

could be used depending on context, but be aware *c'* is more idiomatic.

Comment: Hi. What do you feel about using "abri": "C'est mon refuge, mon abri (contre ...)"

Comment: @LUNA Could be a possibility.The refuge (*refuge*) is the place where you take shelter (*abri*).

Answer (score 0):

The notion of someone feeling like an emotional home to you sounds really weird. I am not sure I understand it well, so these may not correspond exactly to what you want.

You can say:

> ma moitié

It is about the idea that people are not complete without their partner. You can only say that about someone you are already engaged with.

> mon âme soeur

Equivalent to the English "soul mate". Usually someone you are in love with, not necessarily engaged with.

> mon havre de paix

It's not an idiomatic way to speak about someone, usually it refers to a place, but it seems to be the closer to what you want to express. It means "a place where there is never any conflict".

Comment: Emotional home: Humans are social animals. We need loving relationships to feel well. So what gives you sanctuary and comfort in an insecure world is not the place where you live so much as your loved ones who live there with you. Being embraced by a person you love may feel like coming home, regardless of where you are. See http://ind5.ccio.co/A1/Y3/GA/811463d45e9a52a6887beec655257026.jpg?iw=300

Comment: French culture doesn't associate home with this feeling. We have expressions like "la douceur d'un foyer", "on n'est nulle part mieux que chez soi", etc, but it doesn't refers to a person, only to a place.